# Using middle-dot ASCII with proper support?

Tags: html, unicode, ascii, special-characters

I'm using the middle dot - `·` - a lot in my website. The ASCII is `&#183;`, which works fine. However, there are still some problems with some users not seeing the symbol. Is there a very close but more widely supported symbol like this, or is there a way to output the symbol to ensure full support?

Comment: That’s not ASCII.  ASCII stops at 127.

Comment: what's wrong with `&middot;`?

Comment: there are numerous dot- or bullet-like symbols in Unicode, but that one is the only one also in ISO-8859-1, so I guess the others are even less widely supported by fonts. However, I'm quite surprised that there are users that don't even have a single font that has that character—this should have been working for ages.

Comment: Are you writing the actual `·` character in your HTML, or the numeric reference `&#183;`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whether you use the actual `·` character or the HTML `&#183;` entity, make sure `ISO-8859-1` is being reported to the browser correctly, either in the `charset` attribute of the HTTP `Content-Type` response header, or in a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">` tag (HTML 4 and earlier) or `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">` tag (HTML 5) inside the HTML itself.

Comment: You certainly could, though you would have to change `&#183;` to either `&#194;&#183;` or `&middot;`, or just leave the `·` character unencoded in its raw UTF-8 `0xC2` `0xB7` byte format.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, HTML very emphatically *does not work that way*, `&#194;&#183;` will get you `Â·`, independent of the character encoding used in the file.

Answer (score 16):

I can't imagine why a font would lack an ISO-8859-1 character, but you might want to try these:

```
• U+2022 BULLET
∙ U+2219 BULLET OPERATOR
```

Answer (score 3):

Alt+7 creates this: •
You can create the entire ASCII codes from 1 to 255 using Excel. The formula is =Char(x), being x the integer from 1 to 255.

Comment: ASCII = 0…127;  128+ are Unicode, ISO-whatever, etc.