# how to find and replace character in textview in android?

Tags: android, replace, character, ascii

I use this code for replace this • character with \n in textview in android

```
        TextView tvcontent=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_comment_content);
        tvcontent.setText(content[position].replace("•", "\n"));
```

Now I want to replace this char in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnJeI.jpg
but I don't know what is the ASCII code of that char in the image to replace in android.

If you know what is ASCII code of the char please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a middot char, its code is 183.
Also, maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199256/using-middle-dot-ascii-with-proper-support) can help.

**Ok, now I got what you want.**
[This page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm) would answer your question. Brief extract from this page:

this is `OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` and it's code in Java is `\uFFFC`.
Also I typed it in Android Studio - it works (screen below):
[image]

If you possibly need it in HTML - it's code is `&#65532;` (￼).

And don't forget to use single quote when you will replace this char!

Comment: no !! i mean the char in the image that i attached... , the middot was simple

Comment: Glad to hear that ;) In such case, pls check answer as correct (checkmark). Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
String a = "your content with dots";
String b = a.replace("dots", "\n");
textview.settext(b);
```

Comment: thanks but i want the ASCII code of the char in the image that i attached, if you know it , plz help...

Comment: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/dot-full-stop-ascii-code-46.html

Comment: Check this link also:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429546/how-do-i-add-a-bullet-symbol-in-textview

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code to find the ascii value of any character. But for this bullet I don't think there is any ascii code.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         String s= "•";
         int a =  s.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Ascii code is  "+ a);

     }
}
```

Here when we run this code then compiler shows an error:

> unmapped character for encoding ascii.

But in future if you want to know ascii code of any character that is actually ascii, just use this function.